# AlertDialog Buttons - How to set colour and change text font to the +ve and -ve button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-button, android-dialog

I am trying to set the colour to the positive and negative button with Green and Red colour and set some font for the text in the buttons. Could you please let me know how this can be done ?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (v.getId()){
case R.id.bNewTicket:    
    // custom dialog 
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.homepagedialognewticket, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView); 


    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) { 

            }
          })
          .setNegativeButton("Back",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {  
            }
          });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); 
    alertDialog.show();  
    break;  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two approaches to accomplish what you're after.

**1) Make the buttons part of your custom layout.**

You may have to create a plain `Dialog` rather than `AlertDialog` to prevent the buttons from being automatically added.

**2) Attempt to make the modifications after setting up the `AlertDialog`.**

You can get the default buttons after creating the `AlertDialog` by calling [`getButton(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#getButton%28int%29) and passing in the constant that indicates the positive, negative and neutral buttons. From there on you should be able to style the button as you like in terms of colours etc.

Setting a custom font may be slightly more difficult to accomplish this way. You could try setting up the button text as a [`TextAppearanceSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TextAppearanceSpan.html) or [`TypefaceSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan.html) and pass that to the relevant buttons, but from memory they only support platform fonts. It's not too tricky to extend either one to also support loading some font file from e.g. the assets folder, but you'll have to do some puzzling there yourself.

---

Option 1 will definitely give you most flexibility and will probably require less fiddling around. I'd probably go down this path.